# No such file or directory, but file exists

Tags: c, linux, compilation

Last week compiling U-Boot worked without errors. Then I reinstalled the system, cloned the git repository from working place server and installed the needed tool-chain.

Now, when I try to compile I get the following:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdint.h:9:26: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
```

But I went to that folder and stdint.h exists! It's not a broken link, but an ASCII file

Bear in mind that I am new to Linux.

Comment: probably no accessrights? set chmod

Comment: What is line 9 in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdint.h`?

Comment: Could be that there is missing `build-essential`: check [Really bad compile bug :C #23](https://github.com/linux-sunxi/sunxi-tools/issues/23).

Comment: @Felix I have set chmod, didn't work. 

Will look into build-essentials now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `build-essential` package is missing. Similar problem was reported here: [Really bad compile bug :C #23](https://github.com/linux-sunxi/sunxi-tools/issues/23)